# Looking for feedback on Bitscope BS50U. Is it an old design, no longer maintained?

Tags: usb, oscilloscope, pc

I need an entry level, very basic oscilloscope with some logic analyzing features. Bitscope BS05U (http://bitscope.com/product/BS05/) is back in stock at Newark for $55.69 and I'm thinking about buying it. I know the limitations of this very entry level instrument. I've read a bunch of reviews complaining about software quality. What strikes me is an Amazon review from October 28, 2015, mentioning BitScope DSO software v2.9, while the newest version on http://my.bitscope.com/download is v2.8 and everything else there seems dated. Is Bitscope BS05U an old design, no longer maintained?

Comment: I'm not sure. But consider, if a "decent" entry-level, *real* scope costs $1000-$2000, what would a $56 variant get you?  That is (in my opinion) exactly the quality received.

Comment: @rdtsc For $1000 you almost get a scope + arbitrary generator + dig. analyser add on for the scope., decent quality, no eBay or Amazon junk.  On the other hand  there are used scopes, like Tektronix TDS 210 for only 99$ on eBay.

Comment: And you can get a much more capable mixed-signal acquisition front-end to pair with PC analysis and display, such as the Red Pitaya or Digilent Analog Discovery, in the $200-300 range.  I found this nice review https://knowm.org/a-review-of-usb-oscilloscopes-with-software-development-kits/

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you for the link. I'm leaning towards  PICOSCOPE 2204A, but it's good to know about Red Pitaya or Digilent Analog Discovery.